# Откуда коммиты в ветке master?

Tags: git

В ветке master висят неизвестные коммиты:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 28 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

В ней никаких изменений не делаю, работаю с дочерними ветками, а в мастер только сливаю обновления из удаленного репозитория.
После всех коммитов обычно делаю push. Откуда тогда они вообще берутся? Как их удалить и избежать накапливания новых? Повлияет ли их наличие на новые дочерние ветки мастера?

**Обновление**

Команда

```
git log
```

Показывает 5 последних коммитов одной из веток, которые были сделаны в другой ветке и отображается только 5, а `git status` находит 28.

**Обновление 2**

```
git log master
```

Показывает все те же 5 коммитов, а

```
git diff master origin/master
```

27 диффов, похоже, что это ОНО (хотя почему не 28?). С git познакомилась недавно и поначалу творила черти-что, может даже и не стоит разбираться, как это вышло, но хотелось бы лишнее очистить, т.к. эти коммиты давно уже слиты куда нужно.

Сама отвечу на один из своих вопросов - да, эти коммиты влияют на вновь созданные дочерние ветки. несмотря на то, что в новой ветке делают

```
git pull upstream master
```

Все 28 коммитов из локального мастера туда тоже попадают, когда делают push. как же ж их удалить, подскажите, пожалуйста?

Comment: git log-то что говорит?

Comment: @Anika эти 5 коммитов должны быть в master?

Comment: @Anika, на всякий случай уточню: а что показывает `git log master`?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, git log master показывает все те же 5 коммитов, а git diff master origin/master - 27 диффов, похоже, что это ОНО (хотя почему не 28?). с git познакомилась недавно и поначалу творила черти-что, может даже и не стоит разбираться, как это вышло, но хотелось бы лишнее очистить, т.к. эти коммиты давно уже слиты куда нужно.

Comment: @Anika что то мне кажется что вы запутались. В master кто то пушит изменения? 
Полагаю, что из других веток изменения уже попали в мастер.
> все 28 коммитов из локального мастера туда тоже попадают -- это невозможно. Не сделав push, изменения не могут попасть на центральный сервер. Ваш локальный мастер не такой уже и локальный - значит вы или кто то другой уже отправили изменения на origin сервер. 
Чтобы понимать что куда мержите, лучше делайте git fetch + git merge вместо pull http://jeka.by/post/1012/git/.

Comment: @jekaby, в удаленный (upstream) мастер только сливают (merge) мои ветки, которые я создаю из своего локального мастера, а потом отправляю запросы в удаленный. все было хорошо, пока не понадобилось создать новую ветку. перешла в мастер и увидела эти 28 коммитов. делала git pull upstream master в мастере и во вновь созданной из него ветке (думала, это поможет оставить лишь актуальные изменения, т.к. upstream master - эталон). но после того, как внесла изменения в новую ветку, закоммитила и отправила в удаленный репозиторий, туда попали еще несколько старых неактуальных коммитов.

Comment: @Anika, смотрите вывод `git log origin/master..master`.

Comment: @jekaby, статья полезная, спасибо, но очистить от лишнего не помогла

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, после git merge upstream/master по git log origin/master..master получаю как раз 28 коммитов. почти все они есть в удаленном репозитории и были слиты с мастером там. в любом случает здесь они уже не нужны. как их очистить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. посмотреть список коммитов, присутствующих в *ветке1*, но отсутствующих в *ветке2*, можно, например, такой командой:

   ```
   $ git log ветка2..ветка1
   ```

   в применении к описанному в вопросе: `git log origin/master..master`.
2. судя по расхождениям в истории, работа с веткой *master* не всегда ограничивалась лишь забором изменений из *origin/master*, а было (по крайней мере одно) слияние с какой-то другой веткой (из локального или удалённого репозиториев).
3. сделать локальную *ветку1* **полностью** идентичной другой *ветке2* (локальной или удалённой) можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ # переименовываем ветку1 во что-нибудь неиспользуемое
   $ git branch -m ветка1 ветка1.старьё
   $ # создаём новую ветку1, идентичную ветке2
   $ git branch ветка1 ветка2
   ```

   если старый указатель (ветки в *git* являются плавающими указателями на коммит) не нужен, после этого *ветку1.старьё* можно удалить:

   ```
   $ git branch -D ветка1.старьё
   ```

   на все прочие указатели (как на плавающие — ветки, так и на фиксированные — метки (tags)) ни одно из предложенных действий не окажет никакого влияния.

Comment: не уверена, что мне подходит вариант переименовать ветку и создать новую. это же master, из него у меня исходят все остальные рабочие ветки. что с ними будет, если я удалю ветку master и создам новую таким же именем?

Comment: @Anika, ветка (branch) в git — это всего лишь плавающий **указатель** на коммит. в этом — одно из кардинальных отличий от большинства иных vcs, где ветка — это **набор** (ряд, последовательность) изменений.

Comment: @Anika, *что с ними будет, если я удалю ветку master и создам новую таким же именем?* — ровным счётом ничего. какими были все прочие **указатели**, такими и останутся.

Comment: большое спасибо, очистила. надеюсь, больше не будет такого беспорядка:)

Comment: @Anika, я ещё немного дополнил ответ. если он исчерпывающе отвечает на ваш вопрос, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).